# Summarizing Data Within SQL

Tags: mysql

Hi everyone I am new hear and I'm stuck summarizing within my SQL Database.

To make the example very simple here is my data below.

```
GAME_ID       GOALIEID       SCORED
2001             5             N
2001             4             N
2001             5             Y
2001             4             N
2001             5             Y
```

This is a shootout and I want to summarize the amount of saves each goalie made by Game_ID, GoalieID, and how many saves were actually made by each.
The N=SAVE AND Y=GOAL GIVEN UP

I am trying to output my result as shown below in descending order:

```
GAME_ID      GOALIEID      SAVES
 2001           4           2
 2001           5           1
```

Currently based on my code:

```
SELECT GAME_ID, GOALIEID, COUNT(SCORED) AS SAVES
FROM GIRAFFE.MLS
WHERE SCORED = 'N' 
GROUP BY GAME_ID
ORDER BY COUNT (SCORED) DESC
```

But the result I am getting is just adding up all saves and attributing it to one goalie as show below.

```
GAME_ID    GOALIEID    SAVES
 2001         5          3
```

**THE ABOVE WAS RESOLVED.**

**The FINAL QUESTION TO FINALIZE THIs is how do you query for a STREAK in SQL**

For example:

```
GAME_ID   GOALIEID    TEAMID    TEAMSHOTNUM  OVERALLSHOT   SCORED
2001         5           1            1            1          Y
2001         4           2            1            2          N
2001         5           1            2            3          N
2001         4           2            2            4          N
2001         5           1            3            5          N
2001         4           2            3            6          N
```

Based on this simple example: 
How can I query for the most consecutive "Saves" which would be "N" by a "GoalieID" now imagine my data has multiple games to look through but for simplicity I only have the one game here.

My result I would hope to look like this:

```
GAME_ID     GOALIEID     STREAK
   2001        4           3
```

This would show that "GOALIEID" #4 made 3 consecutive saves to win the game showing that the highest consecutive streak of saves was in fact 3. Note remember this will be across thousands of games. But i made it simple here with just 1 game.

THANK YOU ALL FOR YOUR HELP!

Comment: see my ansewer below : Actually you should group by GAME_ID AND GOALIEID

Comment: Please don't ask more than one question in a single post. It's OK to ask another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you should group by GAME_ID AND GOALIEID :

```
SELECT GAME_ID, GOALIEID, COUNT(SCORED) AS SAVES
FROM a
WHERE SCORED = 'N' 
GROUP BY GAME_ID, GOALIEID
ORDER BY SAVES DESC
```

Comment: Wow it's amazing it was as simple as that I really appreciate it. Works Perfectly!

Comment: Glad it helped you, so you mark as correct ansewer !

Comment: not sure if you can also assist with this follow up i added bonus points for that